# How to implement Single sign-on (SSO) with AD user from Azure portal for few different applications?

Tags: java, c#, azure, authentication, single-sign-on

I have 5 applications with different technology like asp.net,asp.net MVC,AngularJS and JAVA,so my company is going for cloud hosting.Now each application has their own login tables, all the existing data mapped based on their login ids. Now company asking to implement Single Sign On (SSO) from  the Azure AD portal for all the applications.
How to proceed? Please help me out with the proper guide.

However when user is login, I am capturing their role and login id.How could we will capture user existing login id when we will implement SSO.Since we need to present the respective user details based on their login id's.How to read the user info from Azure AD Portal in my application.

Comment: A React SPA will work. Register it in AD and use the redirect callbacks.

Comment: checkout https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2022/05/17/easy-authentication-and-authorization-in-azure-active-directory-with-no-code-datawiza/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link, where you can find lots of examples in different programming languages with different libraries used to help you with your implementation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code

If you can't use the libraries directly, you will be forced to do your own calls to the graph api (REST).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0